# Why When I scroll my ListView with CheckBox selected it becomes selected in other item? 1

Tags: android, listview

When I check the checkbox in  my `listview` and I scroll down, there is another listrow checked by himself. How can I solve this problem? Please review it and inform me where of code should be changed

PS: I try to delete

```
viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) workingView.findViewById(com.example.iit.quizzproject.R.i d.cbSelected);
```

but I can't get the position which I want it

```
public class InviteFriends extends FragmentActivity {

    ListView listView;
    AdapterUser adapterUser;
    CheckBox cbSelected;
    ArrayList<String> selections = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(com.example.iit.quizzproject.R.layout.invite_friend);
        cbSelected = (CheckBox) findViewById(com.example.iit.quizzproject.R.id.cbSelected);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(com.example.iit.quizzproject.R.id.list);
        adapterUser = new AdapterUser(this, com.example.iit.quizzproject.R.layout.list_item);

        listView.setAdapter(adapterUser);

        for (User entry :getNewsEntries ()) {
            adapterUser.add(entry);
        }
    }

    public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
        int pos = listView.getPositionForView(view);
        User user = adapterUser.getItem(pos);
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case com.example.iit.quizzproject.R.id.cbSelected:
                if (checked) {
                    selections.add("user");
                    Snackbar.make(listView, user.getName(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    selections.remove("user");
                    Snackbar.make(listView, user.getName(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private List<User> getNewsEntries() {
        boolean b = false;
        final List<User> entries = new ArrayList<User>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
            entries.add(
                    new User(
                            "Amin Ben Mahfoudh ",
                            "24 ans ",
                            i % 2 == 0 ? com.example.iit.quizzproject.R.drawable.lurecas : com.example.iit.quizzproject.R.drawable.elisa,
                            b
                    )
            );
        }
        return entries;
    }
}
```

--

```
public class AdapterUser extends ArrayAdapter<User> {



 private final int newsItemLayoutResource;

    public AdapterUser(final Context context, final int newsItemLayoutResource) {
        super(context, 0);
        this.newsItemLayoutResource = newsItemLayoutResource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        final View view = getWorkingView(convertView);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = getViewHolder(view);
        final User entry = getItem(position);

        viewHolder.titleViewname.setText(entry.getName());
        viewHolder.titleViewage.setText(entry.getAge());
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(entry.getPhotoId());
        viewHolder.checkBox.setTag(entry);
        return view;
    }


    private View getWorkingView(final View convertView) {

        View workingView = null;

        if (null == convertView) {
            final Context context = getContext();
            final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService
                    (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            workingView = inflater.inflate(newsItemLayoutResource, null);
        } else {
            workingView = convertView;
        }

        return workingView;
    }

    private ViewHolder getViewHolder(final View workingView) {

        final Object tag = workingView.getTag();
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;


        if (null == tag || !(tag instanceof ViewHolder)) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.titleViewname = (TextView) workingView.findViewById(com.example.iit.quizzproject.R.id.person_name);
            viewHolder.titleViewage = (TextView) workingView.findViewById(com.example.iit.quizzproject.R.id.person_age);
            viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) workingView.findViewById(com.example.iit.quizzproject.R.id.person_photo);
            viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) workingView.findViewById(com.example.iit.quizzproject.R.id.cbSelected);

            workingView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) tag;
        }

        return viewHolder;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView titleViewname;
        public TextView titleViewage;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public CheckBox checkBox;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling `setChecked()` on `checkBox` in `getView()`. Hence, when rows get recycled, you are leaving the `CheckBox` in whatever state it happened to be in. Just as you `titleViewname` and so on to reflect whatever this row should show, you need to update `checkBox` as well.

Comment: as you may have understood i need to set the checkbox with setchecked(false) so when i scroll , the checkbox recycled and i got a checkbox not checked?

Comment: @user3413286: Generally, you need to set the checkbox checked state to whatever it is supposed to be for that row, just as you need to set the title `TextView` to be whatever the title is supposed to be for that row.